# Combining JQuery Validation and Classic ASP

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, asp-classic

Is it possible to combine classic ASP with Jquery Validate ?

The way my page WAS working, before I spent several days using Jquery validate, is that the ASP function would trigger/process data based on a hidden variable that was changed upon successful submission (of a form on the same page).

Now, however, since the page isnt being refreshed, the ASP function doesn't read this variable. I tried messing with the submithandler/post function, but to no avail.

My main question is: **Is it possible to trigger ASP functions within jquery/jquery validator, and if so, how! **

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. In fact, there is a prehistoric feature called MSRS, the elder grandfather of ajax queries. The client side was run by a java applet, while the server side were a include file that received the calls via querystring. There are still [some articles about this matter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974566.aspx), a [Wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Scripting), [and so](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836659) [on](http://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft%20remote%20scripting).

The point is, you can easily replace the client side with a little jQuery script and use the server side functionality.

[Download here the RS.asp](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4992072/rs.rar) as the include file

Comment: can you please give me an example? Im reading the articals you pointed me to, thank you... I am not extremely familiar with ASP, I 'inherited' the pages I am working on, so this is quite the challenge for me. Is there specific syntax to call the ASP function within javascript?

Comment: And also, if it matters, the ASP uses VB Script... Should have said that to begin with.

Comment: I've done this before, and is not a big deal. Give me some time to build a conceptual demo.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. Basically, I just need a way for specific ASP code to be called upon successful submission using jquery validate (via submithandler I think, but I am open to any suggestions).... the ASP code currently is on the same page

Comment: Thank you... Ill have a look at it tomorrow when I am on my work computer that has my editor on it. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

**

### jquery validations with classic asp

**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        function submit() {
            if ($('#frm_login').valid()) {
                $.post('insert.asp', $("#frm_login").serialize(), function (data) {

                });
            }
   }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#frm_login").validate({
        rules: {
            Name: "required",
            Mobile: "required",
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }

      },

        messages: {
            Name: "Please enter your  name",
           Mobile:"Please enter your Mobile No",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }

    });

   });
  </script>

</head>


<%

dim db_conn

db_conn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=your servername;Database=dbname;Uid=sa; Pwd=123;"


set conn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
'-------------------------------------------------------
conn.open (db_conn)
'-------------------------------------------------------
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")



sql="select * from regist"
set rs = Conn.execute(sql) 
if (rs.bof and rs.eof) then
    response.Write "<span class=""error"">No Record Found</span>"
    response.End
end if
%>


<body>
 <form action="insert.asp" id="frm_login" name="frm_login" method="post" >
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
</tr><tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobile</td><td><input type="text" name="Mobile" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email</td><td > <input type ="text" name ="Email" /></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td ><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit();return false;"  /></td></tr>
</table>

<table border="1" width="50%">
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Password</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Email</td>
</tr>
<% 

        while not rs.eof
    %>
<tr>

<td><%=rs("Name")%></td>
<td><%=rs("Password")%></td>
<td><%=rs("Mobile")%></td>
<td><%=rs("Email")%></td>
</tr>
<%

        rs.movenext
        wend
    %>  
</table>



</form>


</body>
</html>
```